# Error: AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Tags: python, pip, conda, pyaudio

I have downloaded PyAudio with portaudio. When I try to use `Microphone()`, I get the following error message:

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
```

I have installed:

```
portaudio-19.6.0-hca4a3dc_2
pyaudio-0.2.11-py37hfa6e2cd_1
```

I have attempted:

- updating pip/conda
- reinstalling both
- changing paths

None of which seem to work. How can I resolve this? I am on Windows 10.

Note: there are several questions that have the same error message but none of them seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution on the fly I can't give it to you ...
but I can give you another working audio library that I highly recommend: it's called 'playsound' (pip install playsound) and it's excellent!

To play an audio file, just do:

```
playsound (audiofile)
```